# pom use a common dependency for 3 applications Spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependency-management

I have a dependency called "general-lib" which will be modified and used by 3 teams.

- Admin, Child-ABC and Child-XYZ are those 3 projects.  Those 3 apps
  deployed in same server.
- Child-XYZ and Child-ABC are communicating to
  Admin app frequently.
- When we change general-lib version, I want
  that Child apps also should use same version what admin app uses.

Finally that particular dependency version should be managed at super application.

is there any to do that ?  Please let me know if I need to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a ***BOM*** (*Bills of Materials*) where you can move the `dependecyManagement` for the common artifacts and then declare it as a parent in your 3 projects. This is an example of BOM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever-BOM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <general-lib.version>1.0.2</general-lib.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>your.groupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>general-lib</artifactId>
                <version>${general-lib.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

For more details on ***BOM***, you can read the article [Spring with Maven BOM](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom) that even if it's related to Spring, it will explain in a detailed way what are BOMs and how to use them.

Ohter possibility, is to define those 3 projects as a module of a higher level project and manage in this one the `dependencyManagement`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Admin</module>
        <module>Child-ABC</module>
        <module>Child-XYZ</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <general-lib.version>1.0.2</general-lib.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>your.groupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>general-lib</artifactId>
                <version>${general-lib.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```